# Netlogo Having more than one world

Tags: netlogo, quadtree

I need to represent in netlogo a matrix, which is patches with number on them, in both the matrix form and the tree form (quad tree).

is it possible to have mor that one world in netlogo? i need to visualize a world of patches and a tree at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible but you can try modeling a big space and use half of it for your patches and the other half for the tree.